# Netsuite: Manually modify [invoiced] field in Sales Order > Item subtab

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Is there any way to manually modify [invoiced] field in Sales Order > Item subtab via SuiteScript?

Currently I am able to update this field via nlapiTransformRecord(sales order to invoice), but in case there are two item fulfillment for same item, I do not want to combine these together instead I want to show two rows in Invoice. I am able to achieve this by using SelectNewLineItem but the problem is the [invoiced] field is not being updated. Please help. Thanks.

As show in below, if I use SelectLineItem it works perfectly. But SelectNewLineItem somehow failed to update the [invoiced] field.

```
var newrecords = nlapiTransformRecord('salesorder', results[0][9],
            'invoice', {
                recordmode : 'dynamic'
            });

//Temporary hardcoded this to 2 for testing
if (m == 2) {
            newrecords.selectNewLineItem('item');
            newrecords.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item',
                    results[m][10]);
            newrecords.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity',
                    results[m][4]);
            newrecords.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'amount',
                    results[m][5]);
            newrecords.commitLineItem('item');

        } else {
            var lineNum = newrecords.findLineItemValue('item', 'item',
                    results[m][10]);
            newrecords.selectLineItem('item', lineNum);
            newrecords.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item',
                    results[m][10]);
            newrecords.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity',
                    results[m][4]);
            newrecords.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'amount',
                    results[m][5]);
            newrecords.commitLineItem('item');
        }
    }
    nlapiSubmitRecord(newrecords, false, true);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.

Basically, there are two types of lines on Invoices - those linked to a Sales Order, and standalone lines. Linked lines will reflect back to the Sales Order, and do not change stock on hand (as that is changed by the Fulfillment), while standalone lines have no connection to the Sales Order.

The only (API supported) way to create an Invoice that is linked back to the Sales Order is using `nlapiTransformRecord()`. If you then manually add lines with  `record.selectNewLineItem()` they cannot be linked back.

Comment: Thank you for your note. It is true.